# Antialiasing with SharpGL

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, sharpgl

Is there a way to use antialising with Sharpgl? I haven't found anything on the website. So is there a way to antialiase? Because without antialiasing it looks pretty horrible.
Or is there another way to smooth out the rendering?

Comment: frame buffer twice as large and then resample

Comment: oh ok, can you give me some hints on how to implement it?